axios post doesn't return any response
I'm using axios to send a teams notification from github actions.
Below code doesn't return any error message, actually there is no response. Teams message also doesm't reach the channel. What can be the reason?
URI checked.
    axios
      .post(msTeamsWebhookUri, messageCard)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        core.debug(error)
      })
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.log(error)
    core.setFailed(error.message)
  }

